# Setting up a virtual environment on pycharm vagrant box

Tags: python, vagrant, virtualbox, virtualenv, pycharm

I am currently trying to set up a new virtual environment for a project.  I have a vagrant/virtualbox set up with pycharm.

It appears that even though I have the remote interpreter set up correctly, I still have to use a local interpreter to set up a virtual environment.  Is there any way to use the remote virtual environment instead of using a local one?